# How to retrieve dirs in a zipfile using python?

Tags: python, zip

How do I traverse the contents of a zip file in python without having to extract them?

If extracting is the only way, is it efficient if I create a unique temp folder and extract them there then traverse and remove the temp folder afterwards?

Comment: Are you using the [`zipfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html) module?

Comment: @GregHewgill: Yes, I am.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`namelist()`](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.namelist) method of the `ZipFile` class to get a list of all of the filenames in the archive without having to extract them.  For example:

```
import zipfile

myzip = zipfile.ZipFile('myzip.zip', 'r')
filenames = myzip.namelist()
# Do something with filenames
```

Comment: If the OP is trying to retrieve directories, he'll have to use `infolist` instead of `namelist`.

Comment: @Gabe: In an ZipInfo object, I can't seem to find a suitable property or method which would tell me if the item was a dir or not.

Comment: @Adam: Lets say I have the filenames, those are just strings. How can I tell which are directories and files?

Comment: @Marconi: Often zip file won't have entries for individual directories at all. But if they do, check for a trailing `/`.

Comment: @GregHewgill: Yeah, it looks like its impossible to fully traverse the archive without extracting it first.

Comment: I guess that if its name ends with a `/` and its size is 0, there's a good chance that it's a directory.

Comment: @Marconi: Zip files don't always store the directories in them.  If you want to infer the directory structure, you have to parse the filenames, strip off the final filename component, and uniquify.  So something like `sorted(set(os.path.dirname(f) for f in myzip.namelist()))`.